# Python: Why did this averaging code not work?

Tags: python, sorting, csv

Here i have attempted to code something that draws data from a .csv file, creates a list object within python to manipulate, and depending on what the user inputs, sorts it in different ways. Currently i have successfully managed to sort the list alphabetically, and by score, but when i tried to do so by average score, it returned incorrect results. The database csv. itself is formatted without column headers in the form 'Name, Class, Score, Score, Score' with a new line between each entry. Here is my code currently:

```
    from operator import itemgetter

    import csv

    with open("Scoredatabase.csv","r") as f: #opens the file in read mode so it can be read
    formattedf=csv.reader(f) #creates the object from the csv. file that can be manipulated by python
    NameClassScoreList = [] 
    for line in formattedf: #Iterates through each entry in the .csv file
        NameClassScoreList.append(line[0:5]) # Creates a list of all of the entries in the .csv file (List of lists) in the order Name,Class,Score,Score,Score

print("If you would like to output a sorted list..")
print("Enter 'alpha' for an alphabetical score and the student's highest score")
print("Enter 'highscore' to sort by highest score to lowest")
print("Enter 'avgscore' to sort by average score")

while True:
    sortby=input()
    if sortby == "alpha" or sortby == "highscore" or sortby == "avgscore":
        break
    else:
        print("invalid input, please enter a specified sort method")

if sortby == "alpha":
    NameClassScoreList = sorted(NameClassScoreList, key=itemgetter(1,0))#sorts by class, then name alphabetically
    for entry in NameClassScoreList:
        print("Name: " + entry[0] + " Class: " + entry[1] + " Max score: " + str(max(entry[2:5]))) 

if sortby == "highscore":
    for entry in NameClassScoreList:
        entry.append(max(entry[2:5]))
    NameClassScoreList = sorted(NameClassScoreList, key = itemgetter(5))
    for entry in NameClassScoreList:
        print("Maximum Score: " + str(entry[5]) + " Name: " + entry[0] + " Class: " + entry[1])

if sortby == "avgscore":
    for entry in NameClassScoreList:
        entry.append((1/3)*int(((entry[2])+(entry[3])+(entry[4]))))
    NameClassScoreList = sorted(NameClassScoreList, key = itemgetter(5))
    for entry in NameClassScoreList:
        print("Average score: " + str(entry[5]) + " Name: " + entry[0] + " Class: " + entry[1])
```

This code returns very strange extremely large results from lowest to highest, when I would like to display it from highest to lowest.

EDIT ^ the ordering issue is fixed but the program still returns absurdly large average results. An entry in the list ( a row in the .csv file ) would look something like ...,[JOHN,A,20,30,40],[Name,Class,Score1,Score2,Score3]

Any suggestions for how to fix the average score calculation would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: Example:

In the following csv file: https://i.gyazo.com/0615f6c4ec669d5c052ed061e5e871c9.png

Python outputs this upon me requesting the avgscore sort:

Average score: 118183.33333333333 Name: DAN Class: A
Average score: 118183.33333333333 Name: STEVE Class: B
Average score: 117336.66666666666 Name: DAN Class: B
Average score: 117020.0 Name: AARON Class: C
Average score: 101346.66666666666 Name: AARON Class: A
Average score: 101346.66666666666 Name: JOHN Class: B
Average score: 68183.33333333333 Name: JOHN Class: C
Average score: 51516.666666666664 Name: ROB Class: C
Average score: 34010.0 Name: JOHN Class: A

...which is a bit strange

EDIT:

I managed to fix the code simply by changing the line

```
    entry.append((1/3)*int(((entry[2])+(entry[3])+(entry[4]))))
```

to

```
    entry.append(int((int(entry[2])+int(entry[3])+int(entry[4])) / 3))
```

and I'd like to know why this fixed it, because it doesn't seem immediately obvious to me...

Comment: Please change `(1/3)*int(entry[2]+entry[3]+entry[4])` to `float(entry[2]+entry[3]+entry[4]) / 3.0`.  The former expression will be treated as an integer resulting in `0` in older versions of Python.

Comment: Put simple examples that seems to return weird average results.

Answer (score 2):

Use [reverse](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) option in sorted:

```
if sortby == "alpha":    
    NameClassScoreList = sorted(NameClassScoreList, key=itemgetter(1,0), reverse=True)
   ...
if sortby == "highscore":
...
    NameClassScoreList = sorted(NameClassScoreList, key = itemgetter(5), reverse=True)
...
```

should do the job

Comment: Thanks, that solved the ordering issue, just the average score calculation left to solve. Despite how the scores in the file are around the order of between 0 and 60, the program returns 'average' values of more than 100,000.

Answer (score 0):

After a few days of thought, I looked at the numbers it was producing, and i believe it was equal to a third of all of the scores, concatenated together instead of added together. So actually, converting every single entry to an integer fixed the problem, and I guess the 'maxscore' sort method worked because the 'max' function must have implicitly converted the strings to numbers without me knowing.